# why does this string always revert to ""?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-ce

Heres my code:

```
public userScreen(string uName)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        userName = uName;
        string topLogNumber = "0";
        textBox2.Text = userName;
        Conversion(topLogNumber);
        textBox1.Text = topLogNumber;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

private string Conversion(string lognumber)
    {
        lognumber = gettoplognumber();
        int lognumberint = Convert.ToInt32(lognumber);
        lognumberint = lognumberint+1;
        lognumber = lognumberint.ToString();
        return lognumber;
    }

private string gettoplognumber()
    {
        string selectTopLogNumber = "SELECT MAX (LogNo) from Logs";
        string connection = "Data Source = \"EventControl.sdf\"";
        SqlCeConnection connexion = new SqlCeConnection(connection);
        SqlCeCommand topLog = new SqlCeCommand(selectTopLogNumber, connexion);
        try
        {
            connexion.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return "error";
        }
        return topLog.ExecuteScalar() as string;
```

Now, what this code does is look into a database and increments the number by one. When it runs through (I have debugged the whole process), for some reason its all fine, until it reaches textBox1.Text = topLogNumber; at which point it changes back to "". Anyone????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line to get the result of Conversion

```
topLogNumber = Conversion(topLogNumber);
```

or just assign the result of Conversion to your textbox

```
textBox1.Text = Conversion(topLogNumber);
```

The result of the calculation inside `Conversion` is passed back in the return statement. You need to reassign the result of that calc to the variable topLogNumber used inside the `userScreen`.